# Electron code signing and to windows store

Tags: windows, electron, code-signing, electron-builder, code-signing-certificate

I want to publish an electron app to the Window Stores and the cost Microsoft says is $19. Does that include code signing?

I heard code signing certificate cost a lot? Does that $19 cover it?

Answer (score 0):

No this price doesn't cover the cost of the code signing certificate (which is delivered on USB token worth ~$50 alone). You have to buy one yourself from a certification authority.